# Three numbers, x, y, z ∈ N are chosen at random such that 1 ≤ x, y, z ≤ 10?

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand the synopsis for a detailed solution, but I can’t.

Here is the body of the solution itself:

[image]

First Qeust: 
Did I understand the wording correctly?

[image]

Second Qeust: 
What are the two numbers?
I can make the assumption that the first number is 9, but the second I can not assume. Since I am looking for the second number which after division gives 3.

[image]

P.S. formula of incidence of the second number:
$\frac{xyz}{3^{n}} = 3^{1}$

Third question:
We can choose only one of these for our variables. 
Which variable can I take from the two current variables?

Fourth question:
The other two variables must come from the set we considered in case $1$.
We are talking about two variables that, when divided, give a result of $3$ with degree $1$ or, more simply, give a result of $3$?

Comment: When $a$ divides $b$, that means that $b$ is a multiple of $a$, not vice versa.

Comment: No, you are not reading it correctly.  For the first case, $(x,y,z)=(2,1,8)$ is an example since the product $xyz=16$ is not divisible by $3$.  For case $2$, $(x,y,z)=(2,1,6)$ is an examples since $3$ divides $xyz=12$ but $3^2=9$ does not.

Comment: Apparently the three numbers must be distinct

Comment: The meaning of the different cases is shown in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CASE 1

This means that none of the numbers chosen are divisible by $3$. We therefore have to choose $3$ numbers from $\{1,2,4,5,7,8,10\}$.

CASE 2

This means that precisely one of the numbers is divisible by $3$ and that number is not divisible by $9$. We therefore have to choose one number from  $\{3,6\}$and then $2$ numbers from $\{1,2,4,5,7,8,10\}$.